# imageItem returning null in c#

Tags: c#, xna

I have a line of code that is ment to extract the image data from this item, but the code skips as the imageItem = null. What is the likely cause of this?

```
foreach (Layer layer in level.Layers)
{
    foreach (Item item in layer.Items)
    {
        ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem;
        if (imageItem != null)
        {
            Texture2D texture = imageItem.Texture;
            imageItemList[iImageItemNum].itemTextureDataList[0] =
                     new Color[imageItem.Texture.Width * imageItem.Texture.Height];
            imageItem
                .Texture
                .GetData(imageItemList[iImageItemNum]
                .itemTextureDataList[0]);
            iImageItemNum++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do i understand right that you want to know why does your code skips when `imageItem == null`?

Comment: I understand why the code in if (imageItem =! null) is not executing. I would like to know why when I am creating an instance of imageItem it is null, and what I need to do to initialize it correctly.

Comment: You try to cast your `Item` object to `ImageItem` : `item as ImageItem`. If that fails, it returns `null`.

Comment: As was said before you doesn't create an instance of `ImageItem` you take existing object and try to cast it to `ImageItem`

Comment: Ok so I need to change how I cast the item? Or look into why it is not compatible?

Comment: you have to look why it is not `ImageItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception

so if current `item` in `layer.Items` is not `ImageItem` you get `null` assigned to `imageItem` in this line

```
ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will now look into why the conversion isn't possible, but I have no indication of why this is the case.